# How to represent sections of an article with Schema.org in JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'm new to JSON-LD and even after several hours of searching I still can't find clear answers to some questions.

My website is similar to Wikipedia: it provides lots of information about a specific topic, with lots of smaller sections, long pages, etc. 
A plain example of how a page is structured:

```html
<article id="animals">
  <header>
    <h1> 1. Animals </h1>
  </header>
  <section id="cats">
    <h2> 1.1 Cats </h2>
    <p> Some information about cats </p>
  </section>
  <section id="dogs">
    <h2> 1.2 Dogs </h2>
    <p> Some information about dogs </p>
  </section>
</article>
```

I wanted to markup every single section using JSON-LD.
Here's how I did it (unnecessary properties left aside):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
            {
             "@context": "http://schema.org",
             "@graph": [
            {
              "@type": "CreativeWork",
              "@id": "http://www.example.com/example/#animals",
              "name": "Animals",
              "headline": "Animals",
              "genre": "http://vocab.getty.edu/aat/300048715",
              "url": "http://www.example.com/example/#animals"
            },
            {
              "@type": "CreativeWork",
              "@id": "http://www.example.com/example/#cats",
              "name": "Cats",
              "headline": "Cats",
              "genre": "http://vocab.getty.edu/aat/300048715",
              "url": "http://www.example.com/example/#cats",
              "isPartOf": {
                "@type": "CreativeWork",
                "@id": "http://www.example.com/example/#animals"
              }
            }
             ]
            }
        </script>
```

1) After many hours of searches I haven't really found of what type these sections should be. Is `CreativeWork` the right one to use? Is the `genre` property used correctly?

2) How do specify where the section is located? Is it done using the `url` property? Can it be done like in this example by indicating the `id` of the section?

3) I have also noticed that the script gets extremely big if marking up a long page like that. Is it supposed to be like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema.org doesn’t provide a type for sections/chapters. If you want to specify data about each section anyhow, you should use the [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) type, as this is the most-specific type available for such a case.

Using `genre` for these sections can make sense, but I don’t think that http://vocab.getty.edu/aat/300048715 is appropriate. I’m not familiar with this vocabulary, and can’t find a clear definition, but at least the term’s title "articles" suggests that it isn’t suitable for *sections* of an article.

Using URLs with fragment identifier for the `url` property is perfectly fine, and it makes sense to do it like that for sections of an article.

The whole thing would likely be an [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article) in your case (or one of its child  types), and [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart)/[`isPartOf`](http://schema.org/isPartOf) can be used to link the `Article` with the `CreativeWork` items.

```json
{
  "@type": "Article",
  "@id": "http://www.example.com/example/#animals",
  "url": "http://www.example.com/example/#animals",
  "name": "Animals",
  "hasPart": [
    {
      "@type": "CreativeWork",
      "@id": "http://www.example.com/example/#cats",
      "url": "http://www.example.com/example/#cats",
      "name": "Cats"
    },
    {
      "@type": "CreativeWork",
      "@id": "http://www.example.com/example/#dogs",
      "url": "http://www.example.com/example/#dogs".
      "name": "Dogs"
    }
  ]
}
```

All this can result in a long `script`, especially if you also want to use [`articleBody`](http://schema.org/articleBody) (for the whole article, including all of its sections) and [`text`](http://schema.org/text) (for each section), as you have to duplicate/triple much of the content. This is one of the drawbacks of using JSON-LD. You can avoid this problem by using Microdata or RDFa instead. ([See a short comparison.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/328711/63183))